# Regular expression to allow lower case

Tags: javascript, regex, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I want to let lower case also as acceptable on my regular expression

[RegularExpression(@"^(?!BG|GB|NK|KN|TN|NT|ZZ)[ABCEGHJ-PRSTW-Z][ABCEGHJ-NPRSTW-Z]\d{6}[A-D]$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid National Insurance Number")]

How to allow lower case

I tried based on some stack flow solution like below

@"(i)^(GIR 0AA|[A-PR-UWYZ]([0-9]{1,2}|([A-HK-Y][0-9]|[A-HK-Y][0-9]([0-9]|

[ABEHMNPRV-Y]))|[0-9][A-HJKPS-UW]) {0,1}[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2})$

But it didnt work.

Comment: As @RobM says, turn on case insensitive with `(?i)` imbedded or as an option `/.../i`

Comment: tried both..not sure whether i am testing wrong. I am testing my reg expn in this http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html

Comment: (?i) worked . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier just to upper case the input:

```
/YOUR_REGEX/.test(yourInput.toUpperCase());
```

You can also turn on case insensitivity with the `/i` flag in your regex:

```
/YOUR_REGEX/i.test(yourInput);
```

Example:

```js
console.log(/[A-Z]+/i.test('abc'))
```

Comment: I want to allow upper and lower case . Meaning i want the number to be case insensitive

Comment: http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html i am testing in this tool